# Microsoft Edge blocks local server

Tags: microsoft-edge

I run http server, listening on port 10001, on my PC. I can access http://localhost:10001 from all browsers on my PC. I can access http://192.168.1.1:10001 (192.168.1.1 is my PC's local IP) from all browsers but not from Microsoft Edge. When I access http://192.168.1.1:10001 from Edge, my http server even doesn't receive any incoming TCP connection. After several seconds, Edge displays error page that the page is unavailable.

Is there any settings that will allow accessing http://192.168.1.1:10001 in Edge?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Edge blocks localhost loopback.  To enable it, navigate to:

```
about:flags
```

Once there, enable the **"Allow localhost loopback (this might put your device at risk)"** under the **Developer Settings** section.